# Unable to access elements from profile preview page- Webscraping Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im unable to access the "view profile" element from the preview page opened while scraping the sciencedirect website using selenium in python. 
Is there any way to access the elements in the preview page.

```
driver.get("https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092911991930940X#!")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-group"]/a[2]/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="profile-preview-page"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a').click()
```

the error im getting is [image]

Comment: what element You try to click by profile-pre...? I don't see this id in page code.

Comment: I think your xpath is not correct, check it

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi after clicking on one of the authors name there is a preview window opening at which has further information about the author. You can see the page code after clicking on the author's name

Comment: @EvgeniyChiruk im pretty sure im giving the right xpath. its not just the view profile option, i couldnt interact with any other element in the profile preview page

Comment: @VenuBhaskar what information you need from this panel?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi i need to get the university information, h-index, citations and the i need to access the view profile element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
You need to switch in the iframe before searching for an element in it, as here:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@title, 'Author Profile')]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

And then you can click:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="profile-preview-page"]/div/div/div/div[2]/a').click()
```

Comment: im getting the following error "InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid 'id' " while using driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)